# How to get values from multiple DropDownLists in a GridView on button_click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, webforms

I have a `GridView` on my asp.net webform with all the columns and rows created in C# code from behind. Except the first column, every cell in each column is a `DropDownList` with a `DataSource`.

Here is my `GridView`:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gv_Rota" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gv_Rota_RowDataBound">
                     <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6a3d98" ForeColor="White" Height="20" />
                     <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="20px" Width="100px" />
                     <AlternatingRowStyle Height="20px" />
                 </asp:GridView>
```

And the c# creation of the columns and cells:

```
 private void BindGrid(int Amount)
    {
        gv_Rota.DataSource = null;
        gv_Rota.Columns.Clear();

        BoundField bfield = new BoundField();
        bfield.HeaderText = "Days";
        bfield.DataField = "Days";
        gv_Rota.Columns.Add(bfield);

        for (int i = 0; i < Amount; i++)
        {
            int week = i + 1;
            string sWeek = "Week " + week.ToString();

            TemplateField tfield = new TemplateField();
            tfield.HeaderText = sWeek;
            gv_Rota.Columns.Add(tfield);
        }

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Days", typeof(string)));
        dt.Rows.Add("M");
        dt.Rows.Add("T");
        dt.Rows.Add("W");
        dt.Rows.Add("T");
        dt.Rows.Add("F");
        dt.Rows.Add("S");
        dt.Rows.Add("S");
        gv_Rota.DataSource = dt;
        gv_Rota.DataBind();
    }
```

And then on the `RowDataBound` trigger of my `GridView`, I add the `DropDownList` control to every cell:

```
protected void gv_Rota_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                ddlShift = new DropDownList();
                ddlShift.ID = "ddlShift";
                ddlShift.DataSource = DCListOfShifts;
                ddlShift.DataValueField = "SHIFT_ID";
                ddlShift.DataTextField = "SHIFT_NAME";
                ddlShift.DataBind();
                ddlShift.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Shift..."));
                ddlShift.CssClass = "ddl_rotamanager";
                e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(ddlShift);
            }
        }  
    }
```

What is displayed for example on my page:

[image]

So my question and problem is that I now want to save each column (except the first) to a database, as a "scheduled week", and have no idea how to get the values of selected items in all or any of the `DropDownLists` to then pass that back to the database. **Baring in mind, this is NOT done on `selectedindexchanged`. I will select items from all the `DropDownLists` and then press a button to submit the values.** Please could someone give me some highlight on how this could be done? Thanks.

**EDIT 1:** Response explains how I could get every value of a DropDownList in a row or by individual cell. However, now I need to know more specifically how I can get values of specific cells in the **columns** rather than the rows. Is it possible to get further highlight on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Gridview.Rows` property

```
protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(GridViewRow row in gv_Rota.Rows)
    {
       //find this control in this row
       DropDownList dd = row.FindControl("MyDropdown") as DropDownList;

       //OR
       //find this control in a specific cell
       DropDownList day = row.Cells[0].FindControl("MyDropdown") as DropDownList;
       DropDownList Week1 = row.Cells[1].FindControl("ddShift") as DropDownList;

       //this is just a pseudo-code to determine which dropdown was selected per row. 
       //You can improve on this
       if(dd1.SelectedValue != string.Empty)
         thisDay.SelectedWeek = dd1.SelectedValue;
       else if(dd2.SelectedValue != string.Empty)
         thisDay.SelectedWeek = dd2.SelectedValue;
       ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. So with the first method, I could potentially get the values of every cell in every row, and the second method would get me specific cells in the row, to my understanding? However, I specifically need all 7 cells in a **column** rather than a row, as I need to be able to get the selected value for each day of a week. The day being the row, and the week being the column. Is this possible, and if so, how can it be done? (Edited question).

Comment: I believe you can improve this code to do that. This loop should run 7 times (number of days), then for each row, check cell 1, 2, 3, and four using the second example of getting cell to get the dropdown and check if selected

Comment: Do you mean you can have only one selected per row? Could the user select multiple (is there is a restriction on that)?

Comment: I think I can work from this and try get it to work. **For more information:** I will need all selections from every row, but will need to identify which column on a row that cell is in, because obviously i'll need to know what week that shift is. Think of the columns as weeks and the rows as days. So to save an event to my database. I'd firstly get the first dropdownlist cell in the first column to get WEEK 1 - MONDAY.

Comment: WEEK 1 is `DropDownList dd2 = row.Cells[1].FindControl("ddlShift") as DropDownList;`

Comment: That will be the second row. You can have a counter to represent each day as 1,2,3,...7. Week1 tuesday would be row2.Cells[1].FindControl("ddlShift")